# Redirect all posts permalinks from ".html" to "/"

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess

How can I redirect all posts permalinks from `.html` to `/` in WordPress?

To be more clear, for example, a post URL like this:

```
http://example.com/%category%/%postname%.html
```

To be redirected to:

```
http://example.com/news/%postname%/.html
```

It's simple to redirect them one by one, but I need a rule to redirect all posts. My current `.htaccess` setup is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Has this question been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `.htaccess` below the `# END WordPress` line:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*).html$ news/$2/.html [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

This will redirect domains such as:

```
http://example.com/category/post-name.html
```

To the following:

```
http://example.com/news/post-name/.html
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your response. but i want to redirect http://example.com/%category%/%postname%.html                                          to http://example.com/%category%/%postname%/news.html .i hope u understand me plz help http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/98212/ethan-jinks-osullivan

Comment: @anouarpac Updated my answer.

Comment: plz help @ethan-jinks-osullivan

Comment: @anouarpac Just follow my instruction by adding the code above into your `.htaccess`

Comment: what about the permalinks structure in my wordpress dashboard. should i edit it with the new strcuture or let it and thanks @http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/98212/ethan-jinks-osullivan

Comment: @anouarpac Leave your permalink structure as is. Also, you don't need to add the URL to my profile page when using the `@` symbol, just `@EthanJinksOSullivan` will do.